Permission denied (publickey) when copying the key
When im trying to copy a key i generated from one ec2 to another im getting the error 'Permission denied (publickey).' i generated the key and then i did this command "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ubuntu@" it was not working.
How to reolve it. Im not able to manually copy and paste

I think it's saying that you are not authorized to access that instance. Looking at the documentation, I think you need to specify the private key, not the public key.

No, it needs to be the public key - ssh-copy-id copies that to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, once you authenticate through some other means.

If you're trying to copy it within the new instance, then you do not have access yet to that instance, right? that's why you cannot use ssh-copy-id.
You have to at least copy it manually, log in to the new instance using instance connect for example, then paste the pub key within: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and then run
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

if you can't even copy it within the console, then you can try S3 to transfer the Public key
1- upload it to a hidden S3 bucket
2- download it within the new instance
then do the same configuration within the .ssh directory.
